# tkinter's filedialog askopenfilename unable to show filesystem

Tags: tkinter, python-3.8

I have tried for hours now to figure out why the askopenfilename method from tkinter's filedialog isn't showing me any files to select. All I get is this empty window below, no matter what I click, I just get a spinner, there is nothing that I can click on to select a file. I have tried every single google search that has something along the lines of:

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.filename =  filedialog.askopenfilename(tried everything here)
```

This is Python 3.8, CentOS 8, I have even dropped SElinux for a moment, I am running this machine in vmware workstation 15 pro (I am not sure if this is causing it).
Has anyone had this issue before?

[image]

Comment: What happens if you don't open it until someone clicks a button, or you schedule it to open after `mainloop` has started?

Comment: @BryanOakley I just realized I can't even do something as simple as: greeting = tk.Label(text="Hello World") and then greeting.pack()  The window doesn't display the label. It seems not to be an issue with just filedialog

Comment: You didn't answer my question. What happens if you don't display the dialog until after you call `mainloop`? Please update your example to show a complete [mcve].

Comment: @BryanOakley thank you so much for the willingness to help, I figured it out! see answer below

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that I have to enable Accelerate 3D graphics in the guest VM, after this, it started working. I arrived at this conclusion after figuring out that I could not even put a simple label in the window object, it was clear to me at that point that the issue had nothing to do with python or the tkinter module. It works now

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing your findings here :D